# Type Id property error is get when sending text

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-messaging

I use spring boot 2.2 application who receive mq message via jms.

Data is json

In my code I have this config

```
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
```

When I send data via IBM MQ Explorer, I get this error

```
    org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message
```

Is there a way to set this with IBM MQ explorer?

Comment: You might want to look at RFHUtil for sending anything more than a very simple test message.  It sounds like you need to set a message property and RFHUtil should allow this.

Comment: If you have a sample message you want to replay already on a queue, you can use the `dmpmqmsg` utility to save it off and reload it, this will include the full message details including the message descriptor values and message properties.

Answer (score 2):

If your message doesn't have a property containing type information, you can subclass the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` and override `getJavaTypeForMessage`

```
/**
 * Determine a Jackson JavaType for the given JMS Message,
 * typically parsing a type id message property.
 * <p>The default implementation parses the configured type id property name
 * and consults the configured type id mapping. This can be overridden with
 * a different strategy, e.g. doing some heuristics based on message origin.
 * @param message the JMS Message to set the type id on
 * @throws JMSException if thrown by JMS methods
 * @see #setTypeIdOnMessage(Object, javax.jms.Message)
 * @see #setTypeIdPropertyName(String)
 * @see #setTypeIdMappings(java.util.Map)
 */
protected JavaType getJavaTypeForMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
```